# How to verify that a ScalaMocks stub of MailerAPI.send has been called?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, scalamock

How can I verify that the `send(Email)` method of a [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) stub of `play.api.libs.mailer.MailerAPI` has been called?

```
class SomeTests extends FunSuite with MockFactory {
  [...]
  val expEmail = play.api.libs.mailer.Email(
    "Test",
    "admin@test.com",
    Seq("user@test.com"),
    bodyHtml = Some(s"""<html>
        | <body>
        |   Hello
        | </body>
        | </html>
        | """.stripMargin)
  )
  val mailerFake = stub[MailerAPI]
  // Won't compile
  (mailerFake.send _).verify(expEmail)
  [...]
}
```

When compiling the above code, I get the following error:

```
Error:(29, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 /Users/arve/Projects/gradlehub/test/ui/pub/RegistrationTest.scala:29: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
 both method send in trait MailerAPI of type (data: play.libs.mailer.Email)String
 and  method send in trait MailerAPI of type (data: play.api.libs.mailer.Email)String
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `send` is overloaded as the compile error already says, you need a way to disambiguate, which you can to by explicitly stating the desired type of `send`:

```
(mailerFake.send: (play.api.libs.mailer.Email => String)).verify(expEmail)
```